# Is there a fast way of replacing elements of a np.array that contain only 1 and -1

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say M is a 2D numpy array of shape (1024,1024), with entries having values 1 or -1. I want to replace each entry `x` with `exp(-x)`. Is there a faster way to do this rather than using `numpy.exp(-M)` function so that it takes advantage of the fact that the input matrix' elements take only a small number of different values?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you need? If so, I think this is faster than any operation involving a conditional evaluation (and also than using `np.exp()`, as Mark Snyder has shown – thanks Mark).

```python
import numpy as np
from math import e

M = np.random.randint(2, size=(1024,1024)) * 2 - 1

a = (1/e - e) / 2
b = (1/e + e) / 2

E = M * a + b

print(M[:3,:3])
# [[-1  1  1]
#  [-1 -1  1]
#  [-1  1 -1]]

print(E[:3,:3])
# [[2.71828183 0.36787944 0.36787944]
#  [2.71828183 2.71828183 0.36787944]
#  [2.71828183 0.36787944 2.71828183]]
```

Actually, a linear transformation like this can be used any time a matrix with values `p` and `q` must be transformed into a matrix with values `r` and `s`. One need only solve the system

```
r = p * a + b
s = q * a + b
```

for `a` and `b`. The generic solution is

```
a = (r - s) / (p - q)
b = r - p * a = s - q * a = (p * s - q * r) / (p - q)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I would like to know what would be optimal if I increase the complexity of the initial matrix. For example if the initial matrix elements can also take the value 0. Or even -2 and +2.

Comment: you can use the above trick as long as you have 2 values in the matrix, or as long as the desired mapping can be modeled by a linear transformation. Of course, this is not the case if you have more than 2 values and the mapping involves an exponential function. You can still open a new question on StackOverflow, though.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmarking of your initial solution vs Walter Tross's answer:

```
timeit np.exp(-M)
9.29 ms ± 57.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

timeit M*a+b
6.42 ms ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```